# How to counting items for each of the two carousels separately

Tags: jquery, frontend

I have two different carousels on the page; I would like to count items for each carousel separately, the following code counts for one carousel. How can it be converted?

```js
$(".carouselNews").on("initialized.owl.carousel changed.owl.carousel", function(e) {
  if (!e.namespace) {
    return;
  }
  $(".counter").text(
    e.relatedTarget.relative(e.item.index) + 1 + "/" + e.item.count
  );
}).owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 25,
  nav: true,
  dots: false,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1,
    },
    480: {
      items: 2,
    },
    576: {
      items: 2,
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="owl-carousel carouselNews">
  <div class="items boxDiv">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="assets/img/fot_purple_00.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <a href="">Najnowsza inwestycja właśnie dobiega końca!...</a>
  </div>
  <div class="items boxDiv">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="assets/img/fot_purple_00.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <a href="">Najnowsza inwestycja właśnie dobiega końca!...</a>
  </div>
  <div class="items boxDiv">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="assets/img/fot_purple_00.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <a href="">Najnowsza inwestycja właśnie dobiega końca!...</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="counter"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```